# Hide OptionMenu created from the Fragment with setHasOptionMenu(true)

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, navigation-drawer, optionmenu

I've let suppose three fragment, and want to show separate option menu for each fragment along with the common menu form the base acticity. I set the setHasOptionMenu(true) in the onCreateView() in fragment and override the onOptionItemCreated(). It successfully displays the Menu. Now I want to hide/remove the menu added from the fragment as Fragment A menu is visible is Fragment B as well and it only add the new menu buy didn't remove the old one on fragment destroy. Please help!

Answer (score 1):

In the `Fragment` where you want to hide some items, do the following -

```
@Override
public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuItem item=menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    item.setVisible(false);
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because `onCreateView()` is not being called again and we can also not rely on `onResume()` since for fragments it is tightly bound to activity life cycle. A simple hack for this situation can be to use fragment transactions using `replace` in place of `add`. This will force fragment recreation and thus should work here.

**[Edit]**

Or, you can try putting the menu code in `onResume()` of fragment when strictly using `replace()` instead of `add()` for fragment transactions everywhere.

Comment: @ZeeshanAhmed I made a sample project to test it and it worked for me. See my edit above.

Comment: would you mind to share your code? As I tried the same but unable to do that.

Answer (score 0):

For Activity:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    menu.findItem(R.id.action_id_here).setVisible(false);

    return true;
}
```

For Fragment:

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    menu.findItem(R.id.action_id_here).setVisible(false);
}
```